# Rails: Singleton's state persisted between requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, singleton

I am working on a multitenant application in Rails.  Because the tenant's data (access through the ApplicationInstance model) is accessed multiple times per request, I have decided to cache it for the duration of the request in a singleton with a method that looks like this:

```
  def application_instance
    @current_application_instance ||= ApplicationInstance.find_by :subdomain => subdomain

    raise TenantError unless @current_application_instance

    puts "Current Tenant: #{@current_application_instance.subdomain}"
    @current_application_instance
  end
```

This is then used in the scope of several models:

```
default_scope -> { where(:application_instance_id => application_instance.id) }
```

If I make a request to the system on one tenant (test.myapp.dev) it correctly out puts "Current Tenant: test" to the console.  If, however, I then make a request to (admin.myapp.dev), it still prints "Current Tenant: test" to the console.  Somehow the state of this singleton is persisting in memory between requests.

A couple questions:

1) How do I keep a singleton's state from persisting between requests?

2) Is this a disaster waiting to happen in a multi-threaded environment?

**Update**

My workaround for now is to set `@current_application_instance` at the beginning of each request and run rails in thread safe mode.  This way `@current_application_instance` is correct when the request begins, and it will not be changed during the course of the request (thread safe mode). Is this a viable workaround?  Will running it in thread safe mode hurt scalability?

Comment: It depends on where you have defined that method -- that method lives in some class, and that iVar is state on some object of that class. Apparently you've added it to an object that persists from request to request, but you haven't told us where you've added it exactly. And yes, your workaround solution most definitely *is* a disaster waiting to happen in a multi-threaded environment (some other solution to your original design might or might not be, depending on how you implmeent it.